# Data re rendering with useIonViewDidEnter hook in Ionic React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm using `useIonViewDidEnter` hook to fetch data asynchronously from server. For this example, I created a dummy array to show the re rendering behavior. Can someone explain why the data is populated in the console even after I navigate to other tabs. Will this impact the performance of the app? Can this be made better? Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([] as any);

  const carsList = [{ name: "BMW" }, { name: "Audi" }, { name: "Benz" }];

  useIonViewDidEnter(() => {
    setCars(carsList);
  });

  console.log(cars);
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/re-rendering-problem-tabs-so07d?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Ionic Framework keeps all of the pages in the DOM and the component is always there to be rendered when you change location.

You can control the rendering by setting a flag to let you know if the component is visible.

```
const Tab1: React.FC = () => {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([] as any);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  useIonViewDidEnter(() => {
    console.log("useIonViewWillEnter");
    setCars(carsList);
    setVisible(true);
  });

  useIonViewWillLeave(() => {
    console.log("useIonViewWillLeave");
    setVisible(false);
  });

  if (!visible) return null;

  console.log(cars);

  return ( 
    // RENDER THE REAL TAB CONTENT
  )
}
export default React.memo(Tab1);
```

See a potential solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/solution-re-rendering-problem-tabs-6qskh

Answer (score 0):

From my observation about imperative programming language like javascript, they actually processed the value first before calling the method which I guess might be what is actually happening here.
Let's experiment:

```
function a(){
  console.log("A");
}

function b(calback){
  console.log("B");
    setTimeout(()=>{
    calback(true);
  },2000);//regardless of the delay, this got evaluated before the function that called it get called, quite confusing but if you understand the fact that the value needs to be evaluated then it's clear.
}

function c(){
  a();
  b(function(calback){
   x = calback;
  });

  console.log("C", x);
  console.log("D");  
}

c();
```

Note1: while this make a bit of sense, there can be more to it.

Note2: This should not lower the performance of the app except you're doing another expensive work aside from just the console.log.

To improve it is to simple remove whatever you have after the navigation as it makes more sense since you've already navigated and whatever happens next is not needed.